# How PHP change font color of <li> element

Tags: php, function, if-statement, replace, colors

In PHP I need to change `<li>` font color when IP adress: 
Is reachable = **Lime** font color 
Not reachable = **Red** font color

Below is code I have already tried, and it not working.

***Main query:** $stmt = $pdo -> query('SELECT ip FROM cameras');*

```
echo '<ul>';
while($row = $stmt -> fetch()) {
    echo '<li style=\'color: $color;\'>'.$row['ip'].'</li>';    
}

$stmt -> closeCursor();
echo '</ul>';

$check = $row['ip'];
$ping = exec("ping -n 1 $check", $out, $result);
$yes_ping = strpos($ping, 'ms');
if($yes_ping != FALSE) {
    $color = "lime";
} else {
    $color = "red";
}
```

Comment: I suggest you try setting the value of `$color` before you try using it.

Comment: And change to `echo "<li style='color: $color;'>$row[ip]</li>";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the color inside the while loop, before you print the `li` element, like this:

```
echo '<ul>';
while($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    $check = $row['ip'];
    $ping = exec("ping -n 1 $check", $out, $result);
    $yes_ping = strpos($ping, 'ms');

    if($yes_ping != FALSE) {
        $color = "lime";
    } else{
        $color = "red";
    }

    echo "<li style='color: {$color};'>{$row['ip']}</li>";
}

$stmt->closeCursor();
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: This ```echo "<li style='color: {$color};'>{$row['ip']}</li>";``` gives me only **RED** color for all IPs

Comment: Then you never find `'ms'`

Comment: Yup, sorry for mistake, now working :D Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

Put the color getting in a function

```php
/**
 * @param string $ip
 * @return string
 */
function getIpColor($ip)
{
    $ping = exec("ping -n 1 $ip", $out, $result);
    $yes_ping = strpos($ping, 'ms');
    if($yes_ping != FALSE) {
        return "lime";
    } 

    return "red";
}
```

Now show the output:

```php
echo '<ul>';
while($row = $stmt -> fetch()) {
    echo '<li style=\'color: ' . getIpColor($row['ip'] . ');\'>'.$row['ip'].'</li>';
}

$stmt -> closeCursor();
echo '</ul>';
```